# How are Scala Traits implemented in the JVM?

Tags: scala, jvm

I have been reading about traits in Scala. They are pretty amazing. I am curious how they extend a class without actually resulting in multiple inheritance. I know that the JVM doesn't support multiple inheritance, so I am wondering how these extensions work. Is the language just providing syntactic sugar for composition? Or is the code within a trait duplicated in each class that uses it?

Comment: my first guess is that it's the latter :P

Comment: You may want to look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2558317/67566

Comment: It would be nice to mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language is "providing syntactic sugar for composition".

The trait methods become static methods on a helper class associated with the trait.  [See this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637752/using-scala-traits-with-implemented-methods-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, it's actually a combination of both plus a whole bunch of optimization tricks. It's a pretty tricky encoding, actually.

Your best bet is probably to just compile some simple examples and decompile the resulting `.class` files.